# Deploying locally the Web application to client

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jakarta-ee, deployment

I have developed my webApp  with Struts2, Hibernate and MySQL. Now I want to deploy it locally to the client in his computer without installing Eclipse .

For me I was installing wampserver and in the Eclipse I'm using Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost. I don't use maven
please give me all step to do this task

Comment: You need servlet container to deploy any J2ee application. WAMP Server does not support Jsp/Servlet/Struts.You can install Tomcat in client machine and deploy your war in Tomcat.

Comment: install any java web supported server in client machine. Before, install `jdk`. You need`mysql` also.

Comment: @Student You can done this by deploying your webApp's war file on client machine local server(like Apache Tomcat). However, you need dump file of sql and things similar in client machine which is used in running in you own machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **tomcat server**.
Just create war file of your project and put it in tomcat's webapp folder and then move this folder to client machine.
At the client machine past your tomcat at any drive then open command prompt and go to that drive folder like 'd/new/tomcat' and bin folder of tomcat and then just type this command .**/startup.bat** 
your tomcat is started check it on browser.